# Repeated call to C function crashes R - how to allocate memory?

Tags: c, r, memory-management, crash

I experience a crash of R if I call a C function (from R) repeatedly.

I am a newbie in writing C functions and I think that the issue of a R crash I am experiencing is the memory allocation in C. I know that one can free the memory in C, but I cant figure out how exactly and on which parameters. Can anybody help me out here?

I will post a working example here and my issue/question again at the end.

This is the C-Code (credits: the code is based on the code of the mcplr package by Marteen Speeklenbrink (https://github.com/rforge/mcplr).

```
#include <Rmath.h>

void gcmval(int *y, int *ny, double *x, int *nx, double *v, double *p, int *bt, int *et, double *w, double *r, double *q, double *lambda, double *theta, double *dist, double *sim, double *val, double *vpred, double *ypred)
{
  double syp = 0.0;
  double svp = 0.0;

  for(int t=*bt; t < *et; t++) {
    for(int j=0; j < *ny; j++) sim[j] = 0.0;
    svp = 0.0;
    for(int tt=*bt-1; tt < t; tt++) {
      dist[tt] = 0.0;
      for(int i=0; i < *nx; i++) {
        dist[tt] += w[i] * pow( fabs(x[i + tt * *nx] - x[i + t * *nx ]),    *r);
        }
      dist[tt] = pow(dist[tt], *q / *r);
      val[tt] = exp(-1 * *lambda *dist[tt]) * v[tt];
      for(int j=0; j < *ny; j++) {
        if(y[j + tt * *ny] == 1) sim[j] += exp(-1 * *lambda * dist[tt]);
      }
      svp += val[tt];           
      }
    syp = 0.0;
    for(int j=0; j < *ny; j++) {
        syp   += sim[j];
      }
    vpred[t] = svp / syp;
    ypred[t] = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-1 * *theta * (vpred[t] - p[t])));
  }
}
```

**R Code**
Here is a working example that uses the function we just defined in C in R. If I call the call to .C repeatedly, R will crash (on Windows 10). I need to call it repeatedly, and I am not sure how to do the memor allication.

```
if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows"){
    dyn.load("gcmval.dll")
} else if(.Platform$OS.type %in% c("mac","unix")){
    dyn.load("gcmval.so")
}

# Some fake input data
dt <- data.table(f1      = c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
                 f2      = c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
                 f3      = c(1,1,0,0,0,1),
                 choices = c(0,0,1,1,0,1),
                 prices  = c(1,1,3,3,2,2),
                 values  = c(.9,.9,3.1,3.1,1.5,2.5))

# Next lines just prepare the variables for the C-function   
   y <- rbind(t(dt$choices), 1-t(dt$choices))
   x <- t(dt[,1:3])
   w <- rep(1/3,3)
   v <- dt$values
   p <- dt$prices
   nx       <- nrow(x)
   ny       <- nrow(y)
   nt       <- ncol(x)
   bt       <- 1
   et       <- nt
   lambda   <- 1
   theta    <- 1
   r        <- 1
   q        <- 1
   pv   <- vector("double", length = nt)
   py   <- vector("double", length = nt)
   val  <- vector("double",length=nt)
   dist <- vector("double",length=nt)
   sim  <- vector("double",length=ny)
   val  <- vector("double",length=ny)

# Run this code repeatedly, it crashes R
   tmp <- .C("gcmval",
         y=as.integer(y), 
         ny=as.integer(ny), 
         x=as.double(x), 
         nx=as.integer(nx),
         v=as.double(v),
         p=as.double(p), 
         bt=as.integer(bt),
         et=as.integer(et), 
         w=as.double(w), 
         r=as.double(r), 
         q=as.double(q), 
         lambda=as.double(lambda), 
         theta=as.double(theta), 
         dist=as.double(dist), 
         sim=as.double(sim),
         val=as.double(val),
         vpred=as.double(pv), 
         ypred=as.double(py)
      )
```

I think R_alloc is my friend, but I have trouble applying this.

I would be super happy if somebody could help me with a general introduction/explanation of how exactly to use the R_alloc function (there are some cryptic examples in the writing r extensions tutorial but I could not parse them), or any general explanation of how the memory allocation works (for somebody who knows R well but is a self-taught programmer).

Thanks for your help in advance
/Jana

Comment: This C code is awful... that's good that you stated the "credits"..

Comment: You really should make your variable names more descriptive. With the way they are it’d be very easy to use t instead of tt and break everything.

Comment: Also consider trying to break the function up or group your parameters in structs. It's hard enough for me to figure out what order the arguments to `fread` are, much less 20 separate parameters, of which 13 are `double*`

Comment: I am little partial here because of Rcpp but could consider it as alternative as it will free you completely from explicit memory management. Maybe start with our recently updated [intro vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf).

Comment: Sorry if you had a hard time with the code. The comments on code beauty cannot solve the crash of R though. Dirk, I know and appreciate RCPP, but i can't spend the time, for now I stick with what I have (unless nobody has any hints to a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the vector `val` twice:

```
val  <- vector("double",length=nt)
dist <- vector("double",length=nt)
sim  <- vector("double",length=ny)
val  <- vector("double",length=ny)
```

In the second definition the length is not correct since `val` has to have the same length as `dist`, not as `sim`. If I remove the second definition, the crash disappears.

I find it interesting that the crash is triggered only after repeated calls. I can trigger it right away by calling `tmp` or `gc()`.

Comment: Oh boy, classic "can't see the woods for the trees" case. Thank you so much! It also crashed on gc() calls for me, but I misattributed this to a memory issue. Hah!